# Ajax update of google gadget

Tags: ajax, google-gadget

We are embedding a Forex charting google gadget to display stock data into a web page.

```
<script src="//www.gmodules.com/ig/ifr?url=http://hosting.gmodules.com/ig/gadgets/file/100840413740199312943/stock-charts.xml&ampteh names;up_stockList=CSCO&amp;up_chart_period=1&amp;synd=open&amp;w=280&amp;h=140&amp;title=&amp;border=%23ffffff%7C3px%2C1px+solid+%23999999&amp;output=js"></script>
```

The user can change language on the site (by clicking a flag image), which sends an ajax request that returns the body content of the page in the appropriate language (including the link to the gadget).

The problem we have is that the page updates fine but the chart gadget disappears.

Should setting the innerHTML re-load the gadget, or do we have to exec it somehow when the page is returned?